# Call a function inside HTML elemet

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have two arrays, array1 has only the Ids of courses, array2 has the color and id of each course

I want to show the data of array1 [{time: "23", courseId:"1"}] which is an array of objects and only has the id of each course, the data for the course such as color are on the array2 [{color: "red", id:"2"},{color: "blue", id:"1"}].

PS: I don't want to combine them for many reasons..

this is what I'm trying to achieve but I get this error:

> Property 'findIndex' does not exist on type "CourseComponent"

HTML

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of array1 ; index as indexOfelement" #slidingItem>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-note [color]="array2[findIndex(item.courseId)].color" *ngIf="item.courseId" slot="end"></ion-note>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-item-sliding>
```

TS

```
public findIndex(id) {
    const index = this.array2.findIndex(
      (x) => x.id === id
    );
    if (index > -1) {
      return index;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If array2 has `color` and `id` of each course, why not directly use it in the `*ngFor`?

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of array2; index as indexOfelement" #slidingItem>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-note [color]="item.color" *ngIf="item.courseId" slot="end"></ion-note>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: I want to show the data of array1 [{time: "23", courseId:"1"}] which is an array of objects and only has the id of each course, the data for the course such as color are on the array2 [{color: "red", id:"2"},{color: "blue", id:"1"}].

PS: I don't want to combine them for many reasons..

Comment: Read this article (https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496). You should not have function calls in your template because they will slow down your application. If you can't combine `array1` and `array2` for the reasons you have, create a new `array3` that combines them and bookkeep this `array3` every time `array1` and `array2` changes.

Comment: Can this be achieved by using a custom pipe?

Comment: I don't think I would use a custom pipe for it. I would create a new array that book keeps the combination of array1 and array2.

Comment: I ended up combining them, and call a function to reupdate (merge again) each time an update happens to an item inside array1.